# (C++) What does it mean when a data type is between a '<' and '>' sign?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading Bjarne Stroustrup's book on C++ and he uses things like `vector<int>` or `complex<double>`.  What does it mean when a data type like `int` is between a `<` and `>` sign?

Tried Googling but it won't recognize my `<` or `>`
[image]

[image]

Comment: Google --- > C++ Templates

Comment: Try the book list from the C++ FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282

Comment: Or actually read Stroustrup's book with a modicum of attention.

Comment: Templates are only mentioned in the ToC and then they're actually covered in 3.4.  He uses templates in examples in Chapter 2.  I was trying to actually understand what was happening in each example as I go yet he doesn't cover templates until Chapter 3.

Comment: What do you expect us to say that the book you posted did not say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're [templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/).

> Function templates are special functions that can operate with generic types. This allows us to create a function template whose functionality can be adapted to more than one type or class without repeating the entire code for each type.

for example:

```
template <class C>
C add (C a, C b) {
  C result = a + b;
  return (result);
}

int a = 1;
int b = 2;

add<int>(a, b); //returns 3

float c = 1.5
float d = 0.5

add<float>(c, d) // returns 2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for actually answering my question.  I guess I should have read through the entire book before asking a single question